# The application is not installed - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, ssis, deployment, ssis-2014, visual-studio-2013

I need to deploy packages using visual studio 2013 but I am seen this message, the application is not installed, as you can see on the picture below.

what do I need to install?

[image]

Comment: how did you know what tool to install?

Comment: I thought it was, but I was not entirely sure, as you can see on my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently this is because I need to download and install

Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42313

I will get this done and if it all works I will accept this answer.